# Is it possible to convert an array into another array within a formula?

Tags: excel-formula

I have this array as part of a formula:

`{0;0;7;0;0;0;14;0;0;11;0;0.........}`

This is the result of multiplying two other arrays.
Is it possible to convert it into the this:
`{0;0;7;7;7;7;14;14;14;14;14;14.........}`

That is to apply sort of a running MAX function to it. Preferably within the same formula, but as a possibility, in a separate single cell.

Comment: 1] What is the meaning of "part of a formula" ? Can you show this formula.  2] Is this source array {0;0;7;0;0;0;14;0;0;11;0;0} located in a single cell or in a range e.g.A1:A12 ? 3] Is this result array {0;0;7;7;7;7;14;14;14;14;14;14} put in separate cells e.g. C1:C12 ?

Comment: The formula is `=MAX(($B$3:B160>0)*$C$3:C160-$C$3:C160,0)`. The array in question is the result of this part of the formula `($B$3:B160>0)*$C$3:C160`. The converted array must stay where it is now – in this same formula – for further processing, as per the formula.